# Delete FOSUserBundle error messages

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

i'm trying to remove from my form the generic FOSUserBundle message.

That is the result when i've an error : 
[image]

i want to remove the message in the red square.
And as you can see i succeeded to ad my own error message.

I checked a ton of other forum without success.

Here is my code :

- app/MDBUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html ( i overrided the register form)

  ```
   {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
  ```

  ```
      <div class="form-group"> 
      <label for={{ form.username.vars.id }}>Pseudo</label>
  {{ form_widget(form.username,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder':'Entrez votre pseudo'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
      <label for={{ form.email.vars.id }}>Adresse e-mail</label>
  {{ form_widget(form.email , {'attr': {'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder':'Entrez votre adresse mail'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group"> 
          <label for={{ form.plainPassword.first.vars.id }}>Mot de passe</label>
  {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder':'Entrez votre mot de passe'}}) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> 
      <label for={{ form.plainPassword.second.vars.id }}>Confirmation du mot de passe</label>
   {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control' , 'placeholder':'Confirmez votre mot de passe'}}) }}
      </div>
      {{ form_rest(form) }}
      <div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enregistrer" />
      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  ```
- in MDB/USerBundle/Type/RegistrationFormType.php

  ```
  <?php

  namespace MDB\UserBundle\Form\Type;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

  class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType {

  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

      parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

      // Ajoutez vos champs ici, revoilà notre champ *location* :

  }

  public function getParent() {
      return 'fos_user_registration';
  }

  public function getName() {
      return 'mdb_user_registration';
  }

  } 
  ?>
  ```
- in MDB/UserBundle/Validator/Constraints

ContainsUser.php

```
namespace MDB\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContainsUser extends Constraint {

    public $message = 'L\'utilisateur "%string%" exist déja.';

    public function validatedBy() {
        return 'contains_user';
    }

    public function getTargets() {
        return array(self::CLASS_CONSTRAINT, self::PROPERTY_CONSTRAINT);
    }

}
```

ContainsUserValidator.php

```
<?php
namespace MDB\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ContainsUserValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $repository     = $this->em->getRepository('MDBUserBundle:User');
        $user           = $repository->findOneByUsername($value);

        if ($user) {
            $this->context->addViolation(
                $constraint->message,
                array('%string%' => $value)
            );
}}}
```

- in MDN.UserBundle

MDBUserBundle.php

```
<?php

namespace MDB\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MDBUserBundle extends Bundle {

public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

- in MDB/UserBundle/Ressources/config

validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<constraint-mapping xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping

http://symfony.com/schema/dic/constraint-mapping/constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd">

    <class name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">

        <property name="username">
            <constraint name="NotBlank">
                <option name="message">fos_user.username.blank</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>Profile</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>
            <constraint name="MDB\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsUser">             
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>Profile</value>
                </option>                
            </constraint>     

            <constraint name="Length">
                <option name="min">4</option>
                <option name="minMessage">fos_user.username.short</option>
                <option name="max">20</option>
                <option name="maxMessage">fos_user.username.long</option>
                <option name="groups">
                    <value>Registration</value>
                    <value>Profile</value>
                </option>
            </constraint>



        </property>
    </class>

</constraint-mapping>
```

services.yml

```
services:
    mdb_user.registration.form.type:
        class: MDB\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: mdb_user_registration }

    mdb.user.validator.contains_user:
        class: MDB\UserBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsUserValidator
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]       
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: contains_user } 

    mdb_user.registration_complet:
        class: MDB\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationConfirmListener
        arguments: ["@router"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

So if you have an idea to remove these messages it will be great :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your constraint is the same as original FOSUserBundle constraint for username. You probably have small experience with Symfony and don't know that it has [translation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html) disabled by default.

All bundles have their translation files in dot-notation (`fos_user.username.already_exist`). You can override existing translation file or add new with your locale. In that file you can set all your messages for all constraints.

If you want to disable some constraints you need to override default `validation` file.

Comment: Thank you , it's worked like a charm 
Indeed i have a small expérience with this Framework ^^
Again thx